# HTML to PDF converters with commercial / server licensing

Tags: html, pdf-generation

I know this one's been done to death, but most of the onces I've found on SO have been open source. For this particular project I'm willing to spend the money to get the quality, ease of use and support. The less hassle it is to setup and to create new templates the better.

The system I'm building will need to be able to output custom reports including some simple bar charts and graphics. These will all need to be able to output to PDF as well. Again, the less implementation time there is for these reports in regards to PDF conversion, the better.

I've seen PrinceXML (http://princexml.com) and am impressed so far. What I want is at least one other good premium option to compare to.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have strong HTML/CSS, you can do most things with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) - but it's open source. The only reason I'm writing this in a comment instead of an answer is because of that fact. PrinceXML is *the de facto product* you buy if you want a commercial solution. I don't know of anything comparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a commercial one I have worked on](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html). Great support if I say so myself.

Comes with a friendly web services interface so you can use it from most development environments and languages.

Answer (score 4):

I always recommend [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).  It's Free, but supports just about everything thanks to its webkit roots... up to and including script that alters the HTML.

Comment: Do you know if it follows CSS `@media` rules?

Comment: I do not.  If WebKit does, wkhtmltopdf should too.

Comment: Best free option I have tested. None of the other free libs coped with HTML5.